# Retriving data from MySQL to a HTML

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have installed MySQL server in my machine. I created a database and tables in it. I dont have permission to install any other software. Now I need to retrive the data from database from MySQL in to a HTML. Is it possible to achieve it with out installing PHP or anyother software? If yes, Please let me know the procedure. Thanks in advance.

Comment: No you cannot in simple words unless you install php or anyother server side scripting languages

Comment: You need some kind of programming language to create non-static HTML pages.

Comment: Nope... you can't. It needs one of the code pre-processors to be there which can run your codes on server whether is be PHP/Classic ASP/ASP.Net/ Node.js/... etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can use HTML5 for connection with database.
Here is a link how to do that.
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/html5/html5_web_sql.htm

Comment: Be aware that any credentials you use here are likely to be exposed to anyone who views the source.

Comment: PS: The Web SQL Database API isn't actually part of the HTML5 specification but it is a separate specification which introduces a set of APIs to manipulate **client-side** databases using SQL.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. I'm going through the link you shared. I copied the same code from the example from the tutorial and trying to execute. I'm unable to connect to the database. All I did was copied the code in the tutorial in to a text file. Changed the extension of text file to HTMl and tries to run it. Please let me know if I'm doing it wrong. Thank in Advance.

Comment: This is used to create local database(Client side). You cannot connect to your server side database without server side communication. You need to install some software that has the plugins available for connectivity.

Comment: You may be able to achieve connectivity to a SQL database (breaking all the best practice security rules) by creating an HTA file see -  http://dougzuck.com/hta